# sum of 2 subseries is equal

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

We have two sequences of $2n$ numbers $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_{2n}$ and $b_1,\dots . b_{2n}$,  $1\leq a_i , b_i \leq n.$

Prove that there exist 2 sub-sequences, 1 from each sequence, such that the sum of the sub-sequences is equal.
I need to use the pigeonhole principle.

I tried to compare the number of possible sums and possible subseries but it lead nowhere

Comment: So, by "numbers," you mean integers?

Comment: Generating function approach. Let $A_k$ be the number of $i$ such that $a_i=k,$ and similarly for $B_k.$ Then $\sum_{k=1}^n kA_k =\sum_{k=1}^n kB_k=2n.$ You want the constant coefficient of $$\prod_k(1+x^k)^{A_k}(1+x^{-k})^{B_k}$$ to be greater than $1,$ or the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ of $$\prod_k(1+x^k)^{A_k+B_k}$$ to be greater than $1.$ Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: This amounts to finding a subsequence of the combined sequence whose sum is $2n.$

Comment: So this amounts to: If $c_1,\dots,c_{4n}$ is a sequence of integers $1\leq c_i\leq n,$ then some subsequence adds up to $2n.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_0=0, x=1$ and $y=1$ and use the following process until one of the two sequences is exhausted:

$$
\begin{cases}
\bullet\text{ if $s_k\le 0$} \rightarrow s_{k+1}=s_k+a_x \\
\quad\quad\text{then increase x by one}\\
\\
\bullet\text{ if $s_k\gt 0$ }\rightarrow s_{k+1}=s_k-b_y \\
\quad\quad\text{then increase y by one}\\
\end{cases}$$

Notice that the maximum value of all $s$ values are $n$. This is because the largest value $s$ can be in the first if condition is $0$. Then one of the $a$ values is added to $s_k$ which has a maximum value of $n$. Similarly notice that the minimum value of all $s$ values are $-n+1$. This is because the smallest value $s$ can be in the second if condition is $1$ then one of the $b$ values is subtracted from $s_k$ which has a maximum value of $n$.

If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are $n$ and all $b$ values are $1$. This is the case where the least number of elements are used from both sequences during the process. This uses $2n+2$ elements. $s_0$ is given from the start before the process begins, therefore we have at least $2n+3$ $s$ values. There are a total of $2n$ possible $s$ values between $-n+1$ and $n$ inclusive. By the pigeonhole-principle there are two $s$ values that are the same. This means there is some combination of $a$ values and negative $b$ values that cancel each other out. In other words there exists two sub-sequences, one from each sequence, such that the sum of the sub-sequences is equal.